Can we have syntax highlighting for AutoHotkey(AHK)?
I've scourged this site for similar questions, but the closest one was this:
Should we have syntax highlighting for AutoHotkey questions?
But it does not really tackle the question well in that it suggests some kind of syntax highlighting to be implemented for AHK.
And what I want to suggest is for AHK code put in a Markdown code block to have its own syntax highlighting. Please make this possible as:

AHK is supported by Highlight.js
There are 4718 questions as of 2024/11/29 09:46 a.m UTC related to AHK


AutoHotKey is supported by Highlight.js so you should mention that in your post (Stack Overflow uses Highlight.js for syntax highlighting). You do need to make a good case for adding the language in though since in increases the size of the distributable used by the site and would make loading slow (See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355928/julia-syntax-highlighting/368443#368443).

"Please make this possible as it hurts to see all the code in black and white." - no it doesn't. Don't exaggerate. If you want to make a case, stay grounded. There are 5000 questions tagged with it, that seems like a reasonable enough argument.

I've updated my question according to your suggestions. I hope I'm making a stronger case this time :)

@chivracq Clarified~

"It hurts the eyes to see all the code in black and white": The article you linked says pure black text/pure white background (and vice versa) shouldn't be used, but our code blocks aren't pure black-on-white: they have a light gray background and the text isn't that dark either (for me it's #0C0D0E). Are you using a custom theme?

@InSync I'll admit maybe the third point was just how I feel personally and that the code blocks aren't pure black-on-white, so I'll remove it. But I really think having 4718 questions on Overflow should justify the need of adding syntax highlighting.

Non nessicarily endorsing this specific proposal, but if the argument is that we can't afford the byte cost of minor languages, why is ini/toml still in the list, with only 2000 questions between the ini and toml tags?
